# jQuery - Sort list into groups with headings, then alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I'm trying to sort a list into groups with headings in alphabetical order. So far I found a solution of the first step here: [Use jQuery to sort a list into groups with headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329651/use-jquery-to-sort-a-list-into-groups-with-headings)

Then I want the headings to be sorted alphabetically. The nested lists should be sorted alphabetically so that it goes from this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="grouphead">Meat</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Lamb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Pork</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Beef</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="grouphead">Fruit and Vegetables</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Orange</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Banana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Cabbage</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="grouphead">Fruit and Vegetables</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Banana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Cabbage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Orange</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="grouphead">Meat</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Beef</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Lamb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Pork</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/z6j5t0k3/5/

```
<ul id="list">
 <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Lamb</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Pork</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="Meat">Beef</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Banana</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Orange</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="Fruit and Vegetables">Cabbage</a></li>
</ul>


var dict = {
}

$("#list li").each( function() {
    var k = $(this).children(":first").attr('rel');
    if ( dict.hasOwnProperty(k) == false ) {
        dict[k] = [];
    }
    dict[k].push( $(this).html() );
} );

$("#list").empty();

function newList(nam) {
    var r = "";
    for ( c in dict[nam] ) {
        r += "<li>" + dict[nam][c] + "</li>";
    }    
    return r;
}
for ( nam in dict ) {
    $("#list").append("<li class='grouphead'>" + nam + "</li>");
    $("#list").append("<li><ul>" + newList(nam) + "</ul></li>");
}




function uCase(elem) {
    return $.trim( $(elem).text().toUpperCase() )
}
function compareFirstLink(a, b) {
    var A = uCase( $(a).first('a') ),
        B = uCase( $(b).first('a') );       
    return (A > B) ? 1 : -1;
}
$(function () {
    var $sortables = $("ul:has(div:first-child), li:not(.fixedOrder)");
    $sortables.sort(compareFirstLink).each(function () {
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
});
```

I used the code from this ([Sorting nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417756/sorting-nested-lists)) to try to sort the nested lists alphabetically but it didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code attempt

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `ul` tag as a direct child of another `ul` tag.

Comment: I fixed the HTML. The `ul` is now a child of a `li` tag. I also added my code attempt.

Comment: Please add code directly inside the question, not just on external sites where it might vanish at any point. // https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/1427878

Comment: Added code directly inside the question.